# How to get length of specific object of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Why the following line work as I wish

```
print(len(lista[cont])-1)
```

but this one gets me an error

```
z = len(lista[cont]) - 1
lista.append(z)
```

The error message is:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Why I can print the number of elements but cannot store the same value in a variable? Has some way to do this?
This is my list and for eg `list[0]` need to return `15`. [RAW txt code can be found here](https://pastebin.com/pvaEXt3Q).

```
[['1', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU'], ['2', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU'], ['3', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU'], ['4', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU'], ['5', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU'], ['6', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'ES', 'ES', 'CPU', 'CPU'], ['7', 'CPU', 'ES', 'CPU', 'ES', 'CPU', 'ES', 'CPU', 'ES', 'CPU'], ['8', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'ES', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'ES', 'ES', 'CPU', 'CPU']]
```

Full code:

```
lista = []

nomeArquivo = 'entrada.txt'
f = open(nomeArquivo,'r')
cont = 0

for a in f.readlines():
    linha = a.replace('\n', '')
    lista.append(linha.split(";"))
    z = len(lista[cont]) - 1
    lista.append(z)
    cont+=1
print(lista)
```

Comment: If you print `print(lista[cont])` in your original code, rather than taking its `len()`, I think you will find that it is an integer. In other  words, I think something has gone wrong with your data structures and you're not taking the length of what you think you are taking the length of.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Can you, please, specify when this change occur?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh This is the full code. I've edited with a pastebin `entrada.txt`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh It is in the question. Check the 3rd piece of code

Comment: Append the size of elements as last element in each line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `lista.append(z)` you are adding a integer to `lista`, and then when you try to `len(lista[idx]) - 1`, you end up trying to calculate the length of an integer, hence the exception `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

Instead you want to append the length at the end of the sublist you add using `lista[idx].append(z)`. You would also want to use the [with context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) to interact with the files

```
lista = []

#Open your file
with open('entrada.txt') as f:

    #Use enumerate to iterate over the lines and get index and element
    for idx, a in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        linha = a.replace('\n', '')
        lista.append(linha.split(";"))
        z = len(lista[idx]) - 1

        #Append length at the end of sublist
        lista[idx].append(z)

print(lista)
```

The output will be

```
[['1', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 15], 
['2', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 7], 
['3', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 28]
....
```